# Boy gets sucked into "cyberspace" from a website

Tags: story-identification

So when I was about 12 or 13 I am 22 now. I read this book maybe 4 times and completely forgot what it was called. I really want to remember what it was because it was the only novel I read and actually enjoyed xd.

It's about a boy who gets a website from someone at his school and he goes on it. When he does, he gets sucked into cyberspace and rapidly ages. He ends up going through cyberspace trying to figure out how to escape. His only hope, if I remember right, is his sister to somehow get him out of the game.

Comment: Part of me wants to suggest *Lost in Cyberspace* by Richard Peck, but I think that one involves him going back and forth with his friend, and his sister is a more minor character.

Answer (score 2):

#### ... err, well, [Otherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland)?

[image: cover]

I don't actually think this is the one, but it has elements of what you describe. I'm putting it here in case your child-mind mixed things up.

- A series of books written more than 10 years ago.
- A boy doesn't get a website from a friend, but rather they regularly visit cyberspace together.
- He doesn't *age*, but another boy prominently featured in the book suffers from [progeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progeria), a rare condition that makes it look as if you age at a rapid rate (somewhat simplified).
- The boy and many others are stuck in cyberspace, going through cyberspace trying to figure out how to escape.
- His sister is the main protagonist throughout the convoluted storyline, she has to enter cyberspace and find a way to get him out.

#### Points against this to be your book

- It's a massive epic consisting of four books, each around 1000 pages. If you really read all of this *four times* at the age of twelve, you would have remembered it better.
- No one is really "sucked in" to cyberspace as such, they all enter the normal way.
- They boy, while being the catalyst that gets the story moving, is far from the major event and we never really know what he's doing. The book is really about his sister and lots of other people.
- It's *grim*. I would probably not recommend it to someone at the age of 12, at least not the latter books.

I would recommend it to anyone else though. Writing this up makes me want to read it a fourth time.